# prevent division by zero in mass query

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Analytics: mass query with  computations that involve division. Because the data is not clean, you want to prevent it from breaking in case of division by zero.

Comment: What do you want to do with zero divisors? Compute the expression as null, use a different value instead, etc.?

Comment: Use `NULLIF`? `YourColumn/NULLIF(ZeroValueColumn,0)`

Comment: *"Because the data is not clean, you want to prevent it from breaking in case of division by zero."* Sounds like SISO (Shit in shit out) avoidance, best is the clean up the data source?

Comment: Most importantly: if divisor is not zero, i want unchanged beahavior. if divisor is zero, I want to keep query from breaking.

Comment: also i advice you to read [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
SELECT a / b;
```

Use

```
SELECT a / NULLIF(b,0);
```

It will return NULL if b=0 instead on breaking on division by zero.

Comment: Not clear why you got the down vote.

Comment: My *guess* is that as the OP's question is unclear their answer they gave their own question attracted a downvote from one of the same people, @JohnCappelletti. A total guess mind. I see nothing wrong with the answer itself, but the question certainly needs improving. I could, however, see that this would be a difficult solution to implement if you need to change this in a lot of instances, or if you don't know which expression is causing the divide by zero error.